# Python type conversion int <=> bool

Tags: python, types, type-conversion, boolean

It is in the REPL

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 2 == True
False
>>> 3 == True
False
>>> -1 == False
False
```

but

```
if 3:
  print('yes') #prints yes

if not -1:
  print('yes') #prints nothing
```

1. Why are positive integers not evaluated as True when using ==, but they are evaluated as True in if-statements? 2) Why are negative integers not evaluated as False when using ==, but they are also not evaluated as False in if-statements?
   What is the underlying rule, where is it written down?

Comment: @python_user I don't think it does. I don't see the answer to why the integer 2 is treated as True in if-statements, but it isn't when using ==.

Comment: @python_user If all ints except 0 are truthy, then why does 3 == True evaluate to False? What you describe is what I would assume, coming from other languages, but it seems to be not consistently applied in Python. Or I'm missing something.

Comment: If there's a difference between "Truthy" and "True", then this difference might explain my question, why == and if-statements behave differently, as in my examples. For now I don't know what that difference is though.

Comment: @erbcode: A note: "Truthy" is rarely used in the official docs. But they do tend to use "True" (upper case T) to mean the actual constant that is true and has the numerical value of `1`, and "true" (lower case t) to mean "any value which, evaluated in a boolean context, is considered to be true". In practice, in Python, [you should almost never be comparing anything to `True` or `False`, you just use the implicit truth testing on the value](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) ("Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`").

Comment: @erbcode there is a difference between evaluating to True in a boolean context, i.e. "truthiness" and being `==` to `True`. A conditional statement is *not* equivalent to `== True`, i.e for a given `condition` doing `if condition:` is not the same as `condition == True` it's the same as `bool(condition)` Furthermore, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, withe exactly two objects, `True` and `False` and `1 == True` and `0 == False`

Answer (score 0):

Every integer except 0 evaluates to `True`. The reason why your REPL was giving you different results than your if statements is because you aren't evaluating the same expression.

In your REPL you are asking `is A equal to B`. It's only true for `False == 0` or `True == 1`. In your code you aren't doing a comparison. You are just checking that the variable is not something that could be considered "empty/nonexistent" (so to speak).

in short:

`if a == True:` and `if a:` are not the same thing.

If it helps, you can look at it like this:

`if changeForADollar == myChange:`
vs
`if anyChangeAtAll:`